# How to upgrade from CentOS 7.9 to specific version of AlmaLinux (i.e. to 8.3 - not the latest one) - Elevate tool

Tags: linux, centos7, almalinux

There is elevate tool that allows you to upgrade from CentOS 7.9 to AlmaLinuх 8.x (the latest 8.x)
https://wiki.almalinux.org/elevate/ELevate-quickstart-guide.html

While for various reasons I need to upgrade to a specific version of AlmaLinux (not the latest one) - i.e. to 8.3. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is the following option:

```
leapp preupgrade --target <target_os_version>
```

Described here:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/upgrading_from_rhel_7_to_rhel_8/reviewing-the-pre-upgrade-report_upgrading-from-rhel-7-to-rhel-8